# How to reduce time complexity in a conditional dataframe traversal?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm working with the following 
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLFGz.png)

My goal is to give each user a unique hashed ID per month.

So my first approach, very basic was to create a copy of the dataframe that transforms dates to months only, then select each partition with a unique ID and a unique month and hash it's id_user column.

```
df_copy=df.copy()

# Set of {1..12} (number of the month)
months = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_copy["date"]).month.unique()
ordered_months = set(reversed(months))

# Set of all unique user's IDs
ids = df_copy["id_user"].unique()

# Transform YYYY-MM-DD to MM
df_copy["date"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_copy["date"]).month

# Dataframe of salts for hashing, unique salt per (id,month)
salt_table=pd.DataFrame(columns=ordered_months,index=ids)
salt_table.set_index(ids,inplace=True)

# Generate salt table
for i in ids:
    for j in ordered_months:
        # Generates unique b64 values
        salt_table[j][i]=os.urandom(256)
```

So this is my hash function, takes the clear adds an equally sized salt (different for each unique couple (id,month) ):

```
def hashme(passwd, salt):
    return hs.sha256(salt + passwd.encode()).hexdigest()
```

And finally computing this function for every partition would give something like this

```
%%time
df_copy.sort_values(["id_user","date"])
salt_table.sort_index(inplace=True)
c=0
for i in ids:
    for j in ordered_months:
        partition = (df_copy["date"] == j) & (df_copy["id_user"]==i)
        df_copy.loc[partition,["id_user"]]=np.vectorize(hashme,otypes=[str])(df[partition]["id_user"],salt_table.ix[str(i),[j]])
    c+=1
    print("Progress .... ", c , " /4034" )
df["id_user"] = df_copy["id_user"]
```

Now this is O(n*m) complex n being number of ids and m the number of months. In this case it's 4034*12=48408. 
This took about 58 mins to compute which is way too much for something as simple as that.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Why don't you groupby salt_table by user_id, month and the transform it using the vectorize version of hashme? Could you add small sample of your data and the expected output, this will make clearer your intent

Answer (score 0):

## Why is it slow?

When creating a partition you iterate over all rows in df_copy.

```py
partition = (df_copy["date"] == j) & (df_copy["id_user"]==i)
```

This operation is roughly `O(n*m)` and you'll perform this `n*m` times. The complexity is at least twice of what you are expecting it to be.

## How can we make this faster?

Computing a hash is probably not that slow. So, caching the hash might not be required.

```py
def compute_hash(month, user_id):
    """ Your implementation goes here
    """
    pass

df["month"] = df["date"].transform(lambda x: x.month) 
df["hash"] = df.apply(lambda x: compute_hash(x["month"], x["user_id"], axis=1)
```

If you would need to cache the hashes. I would suggest using a simple dictionary.

```
month_user_cache = dict()
def cached_compute_hash(month, user_id):
    key = (month, user_id)
    if key not in month_user_cache :
        month_user_cache [key] = compute_hash(month, user_id)
    return month_user_cache[key]
```

Comment: Thank you this works well, and halves the computation time. I'm standing at 20 min right now, is there anyway to make it go faster in your opinion ? (already sorted indexes and months)

Comment: How big is the dataframe? How many unique users and months are we talking about?